# React нажатия на кнопку срабатывают сами

Tags: javascript, reactjs

При создании приложения на React столкнулся с проблемой того, что нажатия на элемент срабатывают автоматически при загрузке, и дальше никак не могу их использовать.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как быть в данной ситуации?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
() => this.handleClick()
```

так правильно

а срабатывает потому-что выполняется render() и внутри него сразу же вызывается handleClick()
если вы не собираетесь пробрасывать параметры в эту функцию то можно написать так:

```
this.handleClick
```

---

А для того что-бы не повторять каждый раз `<ImageList data={...}>`
Вы можете использовать `map`

```
{this.state.data.map((item, i) => <ImageList data={item} key={i} />)}
```

Comment: Спасибо, а как быть в случае если мне нужны параметры?

Comment: (event) => this.handleClick(event, params)

Comment: Спасибо, но такой метод возвращает мне класс с информацией, но не то что я передаю в params

Comment: первым аргументом будет событие "event", в нашем случае это click... если он вам не нужен то не передавайте его туда, передавайте только то что вам необходимо...
() => this.handleClick(yourParams)

Comment: Cпасибо, у меня есть еще один вопрос, как я могу сделать это из родительского класса и брать состояние именно выбранного компонента?

Comment: что именно сделать?

Comment: Я имею ввиду брать состояние данного компонента по нажатию на него

Comment: не понимаю зачем вам это, но как вариант:
заведите у родительского компонента функцию, передайте её в дочерний и вызывайте this.props.yourFunc(this.state.arg)

Comment: Каким способом я могу передать функцию в дочерний элемент?

Comment: Так же как и любую другую переменную :)